# Alternatives for WonderShare

Tags: video

I am using wondershare video editor software. What are the open source alternative softwares for Wondershare

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: There are lots of, I am happy with DaVinci Resolve.

Comment: Do you really mean open source or do you just mean freeware? The two concepts are orthogonal, but not mutually exclusive.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. Especially missing: What OS should it run on, what features do you need?

Comment: @MichaelS.  A good recommendation but it's not open-source as per OP's request. While we're at it, though, another non open-source video editor that's damn fine is [HitFilm Express](https://fxhome.com/hitfilm-express). It's a free, but limited version of the fantastic HitFilm Pro. Express is super capable of normal video cutting and editing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say the major players in terms of open source video editing are currently these:

- [Olive](https://www.olivevideoeditor.org) (Win/macOS/Linux)
- [Kdenlive](https://kdenlive.org/en/) (Win/Linux and macOS also but with some caveats of not always being exactly up to date)
- [Shotcut](https://www.shotcut.org) (Win/macOS/Linux)
- and I'll throw in a bit of an oddball here, but a VERY capable one, even for video editing and compositing: [Blender](https://www.blender.org) (Win/macOS/Linux). It may look intimidating in terms of learning, but the video editor (Video Sequence Editor or VSE) in Blender is pretty easy to learn actually.

There are other tools, but these are probably the most notable ones, as of right now. If you're looking for compositing, not just editing, I'd also recommend looking into [Natron](https://natrongithub.github.io) (Win/macOS/Linux). Which is a beastly powerful tool, although requiring a bit of learning to get things rolling.